# Faster R-CNN object detection and deep-sort tracking algorithm integration

Tags: tracking, object-detection-api, faster-rcnn

I have been trying to integrate the Faster R-CNN object detection model with a deep-sort tracking algorithm. However, for some reason, the tracking algorithm does not perform well which means tracking ID just keeps increasing for the same person.

I have used this repository for building my own script. (check demo.py) [deep-sort yolov3](https://github.com/Qidian213/deep_sort_yolov3)

What I did:

1. 1 detection every 30 frames
2. created a list for detection scores
3. created a list for detection bounding boxes (considering the input format of deep-sort)
4. calling the tracker !!!

   ```
                # tracking and draw bounding boxes
            for i in range(0, len(refine_person_detection)):

                confidence_worker.append(refine_person_detection[i][4]) # scores
                bboxes.append([refine_person_detection[i][0], refine_person_detection[i][2],
                               (refine_person_detection[i][1] - refine_person_detection[i][0]),
                               (refine_person_detection[i][3] - refine_person_detection[i][2])]) # bounding boxes

                features = encoder(frame, bboxes)

                detections = [Detection(bbox, confidence, feature) for bbox, confidence, feature in
                              zip(bboxes, confidence_worker, features)]

                boxes = np.array([d.tlwh for d in detections])
                scores = np.array([d.confidence for d in detections])
                indices = preprocessing.non_max_suppression(boxes, nms_max_overlap, scores)
                detections = [detections[i] for i in indices]

                tracker.predict() # calling the tracker
                tracker.update(detections)

                for track in tracker.tracks:
                    k.append(track)
                    if not track.is_confirmed() or track.time_since_update > 1:
                        continue
                    bbox = track.to_tlbr()
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1])), (int(bbox[2]), int(bbox[3])),
                                  (255, 255, 255), 2)
                    cv2.putText(frame, str(track.track_id), (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1])), 0, 5e-3 * 200,
                                (0, 255, 0), 2)
   ```

Here is an example of bad results that tracking ID increases.
[image]

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided code it correct.
However, the detection must be done every frame.
Since the deep-sort uses the features within the bounding box for tracking, having a gap between the detection frames caused the issue of increasing numbers for the same person

P.S:
@Mustafa please check the code above with every frame detection, should work.
feel free to comment if it did not

Answer (score 0):

I also study the same thing, I try to combine them, too. Have you done it yet, any progress?

Comment: Please find the above answer consider